# control box showing twice

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, mdiparent, controlbox

In my opening form I am using an MdiParent but the ControlBox is showing twice (see image). I set the ControlBox's property to `false` in all the child forms. But it didn't change. How could I close the control boxes?

[image]

Comment: Post as an answer and mark as such. Your question is languishing in the unanswered queue